# Dynamic change of cube dimensions with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I am tryint to generate a cube with Three.js that can be changed dynamically according to users' inputs. The binding is done through `angular.js`:

This is the html code that allows the user to input and modify the values:

```
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <h2 id="mainTitle">3D house generator</h2>
    <form ng-app="3dHouseGenerator" ng-controller="validateInput" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <p>House length: </br>
        <input type="number" name="length" ng-model="length.value" min="0.001" required />
    </p>

    <p>House width: </br>
        <input type="number" name="width" ng-model="width.value" min="0.001" required />
    </p>

    <p>House walls height: </br>
        <input type="number" name="height" ng-model="height.value" min="0.001" required />
    </p>
</body>
```

This is the code related to the `Three.js` and what I would like to do is to insert the input values for the cube. This is what I would like to reach:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(length, width, height);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xCC0000});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

// dynamically change and update the dimensions
cube.geometry.dynamic = true;
cube.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
cube.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Do you have an idea or a possible solution to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your attention!

**Edit:**

This is the whole [code](https://jsfiddle.net/05stmtus/).
To explain better what I am looking for, this is the initial value.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
```

And this is what I am trying to reach.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(length.value, width.value, height.value);
```

**Edit #2**

As requested by msmolens, I am adding the angularjs controller

```
(function(angular) {
angular.module('3dHouseGenerator', [])
    .controller('validateHouseInput', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.length = {value: 7};
        $scope.width  = {value: 5};
        $scope.height = {value: 4};         
    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller?

Comment: Sure buddy! I am going to edit the question and add it

Answer (score 0):

And where is the issue? in javascript call

`cube.scale.set(x,y,z) // xyz are numeric value of scale 1=100%`

`cube.scale.set(1,2,1)` for double height.

Comment: It should be cube.scale.set(length.value, width.value, height.value), but it is not working. Maybe I should try to include the function inside angular.module?

Comment: And do you using animate function? I mean, if your scene is rendered only once, or it is animated by requestAnimationFrame( animate )?

Comment: It is animated by the second one: requestAnimationFrame(render);

Comment: i have white screen instead if scene. If i remove scale function the same.

Comment: Yeah, working out why. This is a similar example of what I want to reach http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3435/

Comment: Your idea appears to work, but I think that the issue is with binding or taking the values from another file. The solution may be to include everything in one single html/js file...

Comment: then call the javascript function from html input, that is another question. You can simple use onchange="functionnamehere(values)" ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the cube's scale when the user changes the inputs. One way to do this is to use `ng-change` on your `<input>`s:

```
<input type="number" name="height" ng-model="height.value" ng-change="setScale()" min="0.001" required />
```

and define `setScale()` in your controller:

```
$scope.setScale = function() {
    cube.scale.set(length.value, width.value, height.value);
};
```

Depending on how you structured your code, an additional issue might be that you don't have access to `cube` in your controller. A structured way to solve this would be to place your three.js code in a service, inject the service into your controller, and update the cube's scale through a function on the service.

Comment: Seems a plausible solution. At the moment I am using an <iframe> to visualize the three.js. The controller is instead contained in another file. I think that setting up a service can be the best solution.